# Mobile form zooms in

Tags: ios, css, mobile, viewport

I have a mobile loginform, nothing too special.
But when I click on an input field, my mobile device zooms in. But since i am using this snippet:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I cannot zoom out anymore.

Is there a way to either prevent it from zooming in or to zoom out again once the user has pressed 'enter/return'?

Greetings,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`
```

[Know More About Viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: No, now my website is cramped into one small viewport, with a margin on the right of about 100 pixels...

Comment: My appologies, it does work. was a bug in the iphone app itself. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Is not this what you want? Modify meta as (tested on iPhone and iPad):

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```